# Dropdowns and Firefox on Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, trackpad, firefox

I'm using a MacBook Pro with Catalina 10.5.5 and when using Firefox, it has problems with dropdowns.

Firefox runs well, no issues there; but the main problem is any site with dropdowns on it, e.g. http://www.amazon.co.uk or http://www.motors.co.uk - in Safari it works OK, but not so much in Firefox - I have to restart the browser and then the dropdown in Firefox works for a short time.

This happens even with a clean profile.

I've tried disabling autoscrolling; not sure if that worked or not.

What should I do - is there a change needed to be made to the Trackpad settings, as currently I've got these settings:

[image: Trackpad settings]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the screen cap of the trackpad preferences have to do with your problem?

Comment: Fixed; had to upgrade to Developer Edition.